# How can i use the following hyperlink in Google Maps, but have it show the road labels as well?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I am using the following hyperlink to display a set of coordinates in Google Maps.  It is working great.  However, is there a way to have it display the road labels as well?
I do realize that if i change it to hybrid instead of earth, (by changing the "e" to an "h") it will, but our customers are liking the earth view.

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=36.070690,-95.807090%28LineStat%29&t=e

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you link to -

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=36.070690,-5.807090%28LineStat%29&lci=transit

You get the option to switch to earth mode - and when you do the road labels are present...

AFAIK there is no way to enter the earth view with the road layer toggled.

You can see a pretty good list of the available parameters here.

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters